# Passing Object Variables to a VBScript

Tags: vbscript, parameter-passing, session-variables, winwrap

My company recently "upgraded" our terminal software. This software embeds a SAX/WinWrap IDE to create custom programs and macros to use with the software, which is extremely similar to VBA - just without the references to the specific programs (Word, Excel, etc). *Because a VBA solution **will** work is the reason I tagged this as VBA (WinWrap is not popular at all and would never draw any attention)*.

Unfortunately in this "upgrade", the IDE can only support so many lines within the module or else the module simply just will not load. I am now wanting to rewrite some of these programs to run within a VBScript file, but a major hurdle is passing object variables. This program uses Session objects that are important for the majority of the programs we use, but I am not sure if it's even possible to pass these objects to the vbscript.

I know you can pass a string variable to a VBS file in the following manner:

```
Shell "wscript C:\Sripts\" & ScriptName & ".vbs StrArg1 StrArg2"
```

And within the vbs file you can use the following code to retrieve these arguments:

```
Dim Arg1, Arg2
Arg1 = Wscript.Arguments(0)
Arg2 = Wscript.Arguments(1)
```

However, this only works for string arguments. It's passed literally and is not even a `ByRef`/`ByVal` variable.

I have attempted using the `Run()` function:

```
Dim Ses As Session
Set Ses = ActiveSession ' Think of ActiveSession being similar to ActiveSheet within VBA

Run "C:\Scripts\test.vbs", Ses
```

But it failed *(as expected)* giving an **Exception 800a03ec** with no error description. What, if anything, can be done to pass an object to a vbs file?

Comment: You cannot pass references on the command line. See VBS docs. http://download.microsoft.com/download/winscript56/Install/5.6/W982KMeXP/EN-US/scrdoc56en.exe. You can either write VBS as a COM server object and use COM to pass references - see Windows Script Components. Else load your script into script control and make your objects available. Here's an example https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adcae113-4758-481a-a367-60d5d14d97d6/this-is-how-to-turn-vbs-and-js-files-into-exe-files-from-the-command-line-without-third-party-tools?forum=scripting

Comment: An object is a memory address of a 4x32 bit structure. 1 x reference count, 2 x unused, and 1 x MEMORY address of the table of functions/methods/properties (depending on what language you use). Programs cannot access other program's memory.

Comment: When you access an EXE object like word, COM loads code into both word and your VBS, they pretend the objects are in your memory by communicating via a network protocol.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I pass a Python Dictionary as an argument when calling VBScript in Python?](//stackoverflow.com/a/25428465) *(answer is exactly the same, you can't pass objects on the command line)*.

Comment: If you want your target scripts to consume every property of the Session object, then your best bet might be to use an intermediary object-notation format, such as JSON, XML, or YAML.  Then, either pass the object-notation string as a command-line argument to your VBScript, or save the object-notation string to an environment variable or temporary file and open/read/parse it in your VBScript.  Unfortunately, the work involved to transcode your Session object properties to/from a JSON, XML, or YAML object-notation format is beyond the scope of this post.

Comment: Yes, I am aware I cannot pass an object on the command line. I wasn't specifically asking how to do __that__ - but regardless the Script Control appears to be my best bet, as I can write a script and then create the MSC object, use the `.AddObject()` method to inject the session obj into the code, and it appears to be working as intended. Thanks for that suggestion.